# SmartyStreets not getting zip codes

Tags: zipcode, smartystreets

I installed [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) on my form and all works fine except for the zip code which does not populate. I also notice on the page for SmartyStreets where you can try the samples the zip code does not populate. Is this normal, is there a problem with the API or with my installation?

I am using the following on my page:

```
<script src="//d79i1fxsrar4t.cloudfront.net/jquery.liveaddress/2.5/jquery.liveaddress.min.js"></script>
<script>var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress({
    key: mykey,
    addresses: [{
        street: '#edit-submitted-address',
        city: '#edit-submitted-city',
        state: '#edit-submitted-state',
        zipcode: '#edit-submitted-zip'
    }]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work for SmartyStreets. Our autocomplete service doesn't return the ZIP Code on its own. The ZIP Code should populate once the address has been verified, because confirming the ZIP is part of the verification process.

If the ZIP isn't populating even *after* the address has been validated, then there is a problem with your setup. You'll want to check to make sure the fields on your form are all mapped correctly. See more in the [mapping docs](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin/functions#mapping).